# sql - Select boolean strictly true

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select a row Ad as boolean which is strictly true. 
I am using the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT 'user' AS username, 'pass' AS password, true AS Ad FROM users LIMIT 1;
```

However the above statement selects Ad as 1 and not true due to which the below condition doesn't satisfy. ===. Changing the code below is not an option.

```
if($row["Ad"] === true){
                                echo("<h1>You are the admin</h1>");
                        }
```

Comment: I've accepted your *Changing the code below is not an option* edit (no idea why the system doesn't allow you to do it). If that's a constraint, there's just no way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't *really* have a `boolean` type. Instead, it represents `true` as `1` and `false` as `0`, and it uses the type `TINYINT` for this purpose.

If you want to return `true`, you'll have to use a text value:

```
SELECT
  'user' AS username,
  'pass' AS password,
  'true' AS Ad
FROM users
LIMIT 1
```

and then:

```
if($row["Ad"] === "true") {
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Boolean Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html) page from the MySQL documentation we can read that `TRUE` is just alias for integer `1`:

> The constants TRUE and FALSE evaluate to 1 and 0, respectively. The
>   constant names can be written in any lettercase.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT TRUE, true, FALSE, false;
>         -> 1, 1, 0, 0
> ```

So you possibly need to do this:

```
if($row["Ad"] === 1){
```

However, it's worth noting that some database extension and driver combinations may retrieve numbers as strings. You can check actual values with:

```
var_dump($row);
```

However, I think this is one of those situations where loose types come in handy and strict comparison is not necessary:

```
if($row["Ad"] == 1){
```